# Can't Remove a StackPanel by Name from a ListBox in C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, listbox

I'm trying to remove an item from a `ListBox` using the following code:

```
listBox.Items.Remove(stackPanelName);
```

I don't get any errors, but neither do I get any visible results.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var stackPanelItem = listBox.Items.OfType<FrameworkElement>()
                            .First(x => x.Name == stackPanelName);
listBox.Items.Remove(stackPanelItem);
```

This will fail if there is no item with that name in the `listBox.Items` collection. You might want to do this to be a bit safer:

```
var stackPanelItem = listBox.Items.OfType<FrameworkElement>()
                            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == stackPanelName);
if (stackPanelItem != null)
{
    listBox.Items.Remove(stackPanelItem);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend trying to remove items from the ListBox directly (I'm surprised an error isn't thrown as `listBox.Items` returns a read-only collection so calling `Remove` on it shouldn't be possible, unless I'm mistaken). Either way, you should be focusing on managing the backing collection.

For example, if you store your items in an [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) it will automatically notify the UI (ListBox in this case) that an item was removed and will update the UI for you. This is because `ObservableCollection` implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `INotifyCollectionChanged` interfaces by default and so when something in the collection changes, it's fires an event that tells the UI control to update.